# why is my child div going outside of parent div?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want a parent div inside which i can create some child divs which should fit inside the patent div and should not go outside parent div

how can i create a parent div in which all its child divs has same height and they should not go outside it

here is my HTML and CSS

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            html,
            body {
      padding: 20px;
     }

     #parent {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: #ccc;
     }

     #child1 {
      display: block;
      height: 10%;
      width: 100%;
      background: #333;
     }

     #child2 {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 25%;
      background: #456;
     }
 </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="parent">
      <div id="child1"></div>
      <div id="child2"></div>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this what you mean? [codepen](http://codepen.io/motion_max/pen/NxKpZY)

Answer (score 0):

Add float: left style to child1

```
 <div id="parent">

        <div id="child1" style="float:left"></div>
        <div id="child2"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: It worked, but then child1 was getting overlapped on child2

Answer (score 0):

child 1 has a 10% height so child2 should have 90% remaining height
so change height of child2

```
#child2
    {
        display: block;
        height: 90%;
        width: 25%;
        background: #456;
    }
```

Comment: always here to help :)